# Missing header on even pages in \chapter*{}

Tags: header-footer, chapters

I have set the preamble such that the headers of chapter (the ones in which `\chapter{}`) show on even pages the title of the chapter itself and on odd pages the title of the section.
But when I use `\chapter*{}`, for example for the introduction or the conclusion, there are pages (sometimes odd ones and sometimes even ones)  on which the header appears correctly and pages on which the header is missing, but I would like to have, for instance "INTRODUCTION" or "CONCLUSION" both on even and odd pages.

```
\documentclass[12 pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3.0cm,bottom=3.0cm,left=2.0cm,right=1.75cm,%
heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm]{geometry} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}   
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{{\small \leftmark}} % even pages!
\fancyhead[RO]{{\small \rightmark}} % odd pages!
\usepackage{kantlipsum}


\begin{document} 
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\markboth{\uppercase {Introduction}}
\kant
\kant
\kant

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Take a look at page 3 of your MWE when typeset and I think you will realise the problem ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\markboth` takes ***two*** arguments --- not one:

```
\markboth{\uppercase {Introduction}}{\uppercase {Introduction}}
```